# a basic question about the natural Density

Tags: number-theory

There is the same question about the irrational natural density, but I can't find the explicit form about the answer.

Are there any sets of natural numbers with irrational natural density? I.e., does there exist a set A⊂N  such that  $lim n−>∞ |A∩[1,n]|n ∉Q $

I'd be interested in a proof of existence of such a set.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes, you can make arbitrary natural density for any value between $0$ and $1$. A particularly easy example for you is the set of squarefree integers, which has density $6/\pi^2$

Comment: I know this fact, but I need more facts about the set with the irrational number density.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the set $A$ of integers of the form $\left\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\right\rfloor$, where $n$ ranges over the positive integers.  Let $N$ be large, and let $M\sqrt{2}$ be the largest multiple of $\sqrt{2}$ that is $\lt N$.  Then the number of positive integers $\le N$ in $A$ is either $M$ or $M+1$.

Finally, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{M}{N}=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{M+1}{N}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,

Answer (score 1):

Given $\alpha\in[0,1]$ you can define $X\subseteq\mathbb N$ inductively so that $|X\cap\{1,\dots,n\}|=\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$ for all $n$, and so the natural density of $X$ is $\alpha$.